# How swedish is a very very swedish greeting?

Tags: haskell, composition, higher-order-functions

Consider the following Haskell definitions, taken from [this excellent Haskell video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RqvCNb7fKsg):

```
import Data.List
greeting = "Hello"
swedish = intersperse 'f'
very f x = f (f (f x))
```

If we load them into GHCi, we see the following results:

```
ghci> swedish greeting
"Hfeflflfo"
ghci> very swedish greeting
"Hfffffffeffffffflffffffflfffffffo"
ghci> very very swedish greeting
"Hffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffff... (536,870,913 chars total)
```

The first two outputs I understand perfectly. A `swedish greeting` comes out interspersed with `f`s, and a `very swedish greeting` is just a `swedish (swedish (swedish greeting))`, which comes out triply interspersed.

But what exactly is happening in the third input line? My (rather incomplete) understanding of Haskell syntax says that a space-separated sequence of expressions is interpreted as a function call, where the first expression is the function and the rest are the arguments. In that case, how is the outermost `very` being called with three arguments (`very`, `swedish`, and `greeting`) when it's only defined to accept two?

If it helps, it appears that a `very very swedish greeting` is equivalent to a `swedish $ swedish $ swedish $ swedish $  ... (27 layers of swedish) ... $ swedish $ swedish greeting`.

Comment: modern swedes greet "Hi"!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You said:

> My (rather incomplete) understanding of Haskell syntax says that a space-separated sequence of expressions is interpreted as a function call, where the first expression is the function and the rest are the arguments.

You are correct that this is not a complete understanding of what is actually going on. From your example:

```
very very swedish greeting
```

This is the same as:

```
((very very) swedish) greeting
```

This is because function application is left associative. Furthermore, every function in Haskell takes one input and returns one result. What you think of as functions accepting multiple inputs are, in reality, functions that accept a single input and return a function as their result.

This also explains why arrows (->) delimit function inputs *and* results in function types. Consider the type of `++`:

```
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

This is the same as:

```
(++) :: [a] -> ([a] -> [a])
```

You may think of the `++` operator as taking two lists and returning a list, but in reality it is a function of one input (a list) that returns a function of one input (another list) that returns a list.

Taken all together, you can hopefully see that `very very` is a valid expression by itself (and happens to have the same type as `very`).

```
very very x
```

is equivalent to:

```
very (very (very x))
```

Comment: Any reason why `very very x` doesn't create an infinite loop?

Answer (score 3):

Function application is left associative, so

```
very very swedish greeting
```

is equivalent to

```
((very very) swedish) greeting
```

---

`very` has type `(t -> t) -> t -> t`. `very` can be passed as the first argument to `very`

```
very      :: (t        -> t       ) -> t        -> t
     very ::  (t -> t) -> (t -> t)
very very ::                           (t -> t) -> (t -> t)
```

`very very` is also a function, it has the type `(t -> t) -> t -> t`. Since `swedish` has the type `String -> String` it can be passed to `very very`. The resulting function has type `String -> String`

```
((very very) swedish) :: String -> String
```

A function with type `String -> String` can be applied to `greeting :: String`

```
(((very very) swedish) greeting) :: String
```

Answer (score 1):

Daniel Pratt's answer explains what is happening on the syntactic level. But  why does `(very very)` result in `swedish` being applied 27 times and not some other number? In order to figure this out, let's make a function that is more general than `very` which applies a function `n` times:

```
-- Takes number of times to apply `n` and a function `f`, and returns a
-- function that applies `f` `n` times.
appn n f
  | n == 1    = f
  | otherwise = f . (appn (n - 1) f)

-- If necessary, you could define very = (appn 3)
very = (appn 3)
```

And let's stop using `swedish` and instead use `(+1)` so it's easier to count how many times the function is applied:

```
Vandelay Industries> (appn 3) (appn 3) (+1) 0
27
Vandelay Industries> (appn 2) (appn 3) (+1) 0
9
Vandelay Industries> (appn 2) (appn 4) (+1) 0
16
Vandelay Industries> (appn 4) (appn 10) (+1) 0
10000
Vandelay Industries> (appn 2) (appn 2) (appn 2) (+1) 0
16
```

You may see the pattern by now. `(appn x) (appn y)` generates the equivalent of `appn $ y ^ x`. But why? Consider `(appn 2) (appn 3)`. The `(appn 3)` means `f (f (f x))` or `f . f . f`. Put that through `(appn 2)` and each `f` is actually applied 3 times: `(f . f . f) . (f . f . f) . (f . f . f)` or 9 times total.